# Visual studio web deploy not allowing untrustedcertificates

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

I'm trying to publish ASP.NET web api project using web deploy and the following error occurs.

> Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer
>   ("xxxxx") using the specified process ("Web Management
>   Service"), but could not verify the server’s certificate. If you trust
>   the server, connect again and allow untrusted certificates.  Learn
>   more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED.)

1. Imported the certificate from MSDeployServiceURL to Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder.
2. I also tried to deploy from remote machine (xxxxx) for it's IIS instance and apparently it's not trusting it's own certificate either.
3. `<AllowUntrustedCertificate>true</AllowUntrustedCertificate>` to the pubxml file.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Looks like this issue should be resolved in the next VS 2017 update -> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/33263/vs2017-web-deploy-aspnet-mvc-core-failed-due-to-un.html

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue. It seems to be intermittent and with no clear cause.

The only solution I've found is to re-import the pubxml file which was created by IIS for web deploy.

Its not really a fix as it keeps re-occurring however the work around may help if you're struggling to redeploy quickly.